# Generar un script en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Necesito ayuda para generar un script que me permita ejecutar una acción en este caso un `GRANT`, el ejemplo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    select 'GRANT insert, select, delete, update on '+ name + ' TO 
    bodeguero' from BODEGA.sys.tables
```

de que manera puedo ejecutar esta consulta automáticamente, pues me retorna esta consulta:

```
 grant insert, select, delete, update on BOD_CABEZATOMA to bodeguero
 grant insert, select, delete, update on BOD_CAB_EGRESO_BODEGA to bodeguero  

 grant insert, select, delete, update on BOD_CAB_INGRESO_BODEGA to bodeguero
 grant insert, select, delete, update on BOD_DETALLEEGRESO to bodeguero
```

Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías considerar la concatenación de cada fila en una variable, al final lo ejecutas con `EXEC`.

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SCRIPT = ''

SELECT @SCRIPT = @SCRIPT + 'GRANT insert, select, delete, update on '+ name + ' TO bodeguero '
FROM BODEGA.sys.tables

EXEC (@SCRIPT)
```

Antes de ejecutarla podrías usar `PRINT @SCRIPT` para verificar que esté construyendo correctamente tu consulta.

---

**Referencia:**

- [EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, fue de utilidad aun tengo una duda, al ejecutar por separado muestra un error: 

    _Debe declarar la variable escalar "@SCRIPT"_

A que se puede deber?

Comment: @Javtronic ¿Cómo lo ejecutas por separado?

Comment: Al momento de de ejecutar de manera individual, cada una de la lineas sugeridas, en la linea de select muestra un error que indica:
**Mens. 137, Nivel 15, Estado 2, Línea 2
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@SCRIPT".**

Comment: @Javtronic no entiendo cuando dices de manera individual, debido a que en la respuesta que proponga se concatena una cadena por cada registro, para que al final se ejecute en conjunto. Asimismo, el problema en la declaración de la variable sería en la inicialización, cambié `DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX) = ''` por `DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(MAX) SELECT @SCRIPT = ''`.  En algunas versiones es diferente la inicialización de variables.

Comment: La inicialización de la variable fue en esta ocación, entedi muy bien el concepto y su funcionamiento..